# Have I used "Such a" in an appropriate way?

Tags: word-usage, word-order

Have I used "Such a" in an appropriate way?

Congratulations for having  such a little bundle of joy.

Comment: You may want to say "such a wonderful bundle of joy". The way you've written it, the emphasis is on "little", unless that's what you meant.

Comment: Not what you asked about, but when congratulating someone you should say  "Congratulations *on* [something]".

Comment: One thing to note about “such a” is that it is used when you have seen or noticed something.   If you are sending a “congratulations” note, it would be strange to say “such a little bundle of joy” if you have NOT seen the baby yet.    If you have seen the baby, this is fine.  If you have not yet seen the baby, try “congratulations on your new bundle of joy” — without the such.

Comment: The sentence is an odd thing to say. It might be better to simply say “Congratulations on your bundle of joy.”

Comment: If by little, you were aiming for cute, I suggest *congratulations for having such a cute bundle of joy* (Although, I'm guessing by now, that bundle of joy has turned into a tyke :D)

Answer (score 1):

"Such a..." emphasizes whatever word you follow it with. As @peter mentioned, the word your emphasizing here is that the bundle of joy is little, which would be uncommon.

> Def: Such
>
> > Used before a noun or noun phrase to add emphasis. [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/such)

Such **a** should be used in the same way, but for singular countable nouns.

Long story short, what you have said is grammatically correct, but probably not exactly what you're aiming for.

Comment: With respect, I disagree a little — it’s very understandable because people often talk **cutely** about newborn babies.

Comment: I think @Bee is right for the most part, however, the rules of written and spoken English vary quite a bit, so it is very understandable to use "such a little bundle of joy" to congratulate someone on having a newborn baby.